# Simplify an awk "nth column sum"

Tags: bash, awk, simplify

Could you help me simplify:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{rank=1/((1/$6)+(1/$10)+(1/$14)+(1/$18)+(1/$22));print $0,rank}' test.csv
```

I know the for loop should be:

```
for(i=6; i<=NF; i+=4)
```

But I don't know how to make a repeating pattern in AWK. Also not sure how awk handles dividing by zero.

Sample data:

```
04/12/10 01:15,1291425300,279,41,6,24,71,39,12,1,356,25,4,29,32,10,1,1,170,27,16,8
21/05/14 16:45,1400690700,147,28,80,13,99,7,121,11,107,19,132,12,119,24,40,10,154,25,161,20
09/10/07 09:45,1191923100,152,56,201,35,115,47,157,29,149,47,119,19,131,40,30,11,216,136,213,64
08/06/07 00:30,1181262600,133,47,268,41,93,26,282,40,151,30,249,39,160,46,191,45,164,64,216,42
13/11/09 06:15,1258092900,1043,1462,1163,1456,789,1111,930,1143,954,1460,1366,1469,831,891,728,954,1092,1316,1381,1492
10/03/98 19:30,889558200,789,1240,1176,1262,,,,,,,,,,,,,162,271,1006,283
```

Sample output:

```
04/12/10 01:15,1291425300,279,41,6,24,71,39,12,1,356,25,4,29,32,10,1,1,170,27,16,8,0.454308093994778
21/05/14 16:45,1400690700,147,28,80,13,99,7,121,11,107,19,132,12,119,24,40,10,154,25,161,20,2.49273678094131
09/10/07 09:45,1191923100,152,56,201,35,115,47,157,29,149,47,119,19,131,40,30,11,216,136,213,64,4.50004789527607
08/06/07 00:30,1181262600,133,47,268,41,93,26,282,40,151,30,249,39,160,46,191,45,164,64,216,42,8.2601610016789
13/11/09 06:15,1258092900,1043,1462,1163,1456,789,1111,930,1143,954,1460,1366,1469,831,891,728,954,1092,1316,1381,1492,252.467979545275
10/03/98 19:30,889558200,789,1240,1176,1262,,,,,,,,,,,,,162,271,1006,283,#DIV/0!
```

Comment: *"not sure how awk handles dividing by zero.*" : Learn to run simple tests to answer your own questions: `awk 'BEGIN{print 6 / 0 }' /dev/null` produces `awk: division by zero source line number 1`. Good luck.
 source line number 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{rank=0;for(i=6;i<=22;i+=4)rank+=($i ? 1/$i : 0);print $0,rank}
```

Comment: oh yes, missed the dividing by zero part

Comment: also where would one add something like `if($i+0==0) {$i=99999} else {$i==$i}`to deal with division of zeros?

Comment: solved it, thanks!
`awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{rank=0;for(i=6;i<=NF;i+=4)rank+=($i+0!=0 ? 1/$i : 1/99999);ranki=(1/rank);print $0,ranki}' test.csv`

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," } 
{
   for(i=6;i<=NF;i+=4)     # every 4th column
       if($i+0==0) {       # if there is a 0 divisor
           rank="#DIV/0!"  # set rank to something static
           break           # break from for
       } 
       else 
           rank+=1/$i      # sum every 4th
   print $0,rank           # output
   rank=0                  # reset
}' file
```

Outputs (didn't check if they were right):

```
04/12/10 01:15,1291425300,279,41,6,24,71,39,12,1,356,25,4,29,32,10,1,1,170,27,16,8,2.20115
21/05/14 16:45,1400690700,147,28,80,13,99,7,121,11,107,19,132,12,119,24,40,10,154,25,161,20,0.401166
09/10/07 09:45,1191923100,152,56,201,35,115,47,157,29,149,47,119,19,131,40,30,11,216,136,213,64,0.22222
08/06/07 00:30,1181262600,133,47,268,41,93,26,282,40,151,30,249,39,160,46,191,45,164,64,216,42,0.121063
13/11/09 06:15,1258092900,1043,1462,1163,1456,789,1111,930,1143,954,1460,1366,1469,831,891,728,954,1092,1316,1381,1492,0.0039609
10/03/98 19:30,889558200,789,1240,1176,1262,,,,,,,,,,,,,162,271,1006,283,#DIV/0!
```